# Where did my reputation and badges go?

Tags: support, openid, user-accounts, merge-accounts

I tried to associate my FB openid with my SO account and it logged me in as a new user with a 101 reputation.

Now I can't seem to log into FB with my old history.  How do I go about recovering my old SO account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the problem:

> https://stackoverflow.com/users/30436/larry-osterman

and

> https://stackoverflow.com/users/761503/larry-osterman

You accidentally created 2 accounts somehow.  Ask a moderator to merge them.

You don't have the high-rep account associated with your other accounts.

Answer (score 5):

I've merged your accounts... *with my mind!*

Comment: The merge is strong in this one.